# ASP.NET and IIS impersonate not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET Application and I have the authentication set to Windows Authentication, which is working, but now I am trying to impersonate the user so if they login into Windows, they will by-pass the login and the login dialog box.

I have these set in my web.config under system.web:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

and I have this set under system.webServer:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

and in my IIS I have Windows Authentication enabled, ASP.NET Impersonate to Enabled and Anonymous Authentication disabled.

But I still get the Windows Authentication Login Window, when I am login and I am able to bypass the authentication on another intranet site we have (but don't have access to)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Impersonation isn't for bypassing the login window. It's for something completely different.

Comment: @mason I thought that what is what for....how would I bypass the windows authentication login window and the user is already login?